# Set PHP variable from file name

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and am trying to choose a file from a directory, then use that file name to set a `$filename` variable, so I can then process the file (open, loop through, etc.). However, `$filename` remains null after I've chosen it.

```
<?php
    $filename = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $filename = test_input($_POST["filename"]);
    }

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="processFile.php">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" action="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

processFile.php:

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST['filename']; 
$handle = fopen ($filename, "r");

$header = fgetcsv($handle, '', "\t"); // gets a row at a time, so first row
fclose($handle);

print "<br />";

$cols = $header;

$length = count($cols);

var_dump($cols);

print "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a bit hard to understand, could you clarify it a bit? You're using `fgetcsv` to read a file, is it supposed to be a csv file? Also, what's the purpose of the code in the first clip?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a file upload or are you actually reading a server file?  Read [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: I think the problem is getting the full path of the file... Looking into that

Comment: Not uploading the file; I just want to process a tab-delimited text file, and then I will be submitting data to a SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code to your form to enable file upload

```
<form method="POST" action="processFile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" action="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is missing a valid enctype `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and you're using `$_POST` rather than `$_FILES` which is required when dealing with files.

- Place `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your form tags.
- Change all instances of `$_POST['filename']` to `$_FILES['filename']`
- Remove `action="Submit"` from your input. Action is reserved for `<form>` and not inputs.

Resources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

---

> *Actually, this fixes it: $name = $_FILES['filename']['name']; –  sqldoug*

- As outlined in the documentation/resources links.

Comment: @sqldoug Sidenote: I have to leave for a bit but will be back later if you have any questions, *cheers*

Comment: print_r($_FILES); gives the right file name, but not its full path, which I think is the problem. The file to process is not in the same directory as the php files; it's outside of any web server directories.

Comment: Actually, this fixes it: `$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];`

Comment: @sqldoug ok. Well, I was under the impression you would have accepted my answer. You got your solution and that's what counts. The links I gave you in there, covers that also.